# Dinner before claiming baggage

Tags: luggage

My daughter an I are flying home together; she has a layover at IAH which is my final destination.  I would like to have dinner with her then pick up my bags to head home.  What happens to my luggage while I have dinner?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. It's a little unclear what you are asking. Are you wondering if you can bring bags to a restaurant? Are you asking if there is storage available at IAH? If you were thinking of just not claiming the bags until after dinner, I would very strongly recommend against it. The bags could be locked up in the baggage office as unclaimed, and you might not be able to retrieve them till the next day, they could be picked up accidentally by someone else (or stolen), or they could even be confiscated.

Comment: @choster She wants to eat dinner with her friend airside after deplaning and only leave the secure area after dinner

Comment: I've found it not at all unusual for travelers to lug large bags in/through/out airport restaurants...

Comment: @brhans I think the point is that the daughter will not want to leave the secure area, or have time to, or whatever.  Therefore, the OP will have to leave her daughter before getting her bags, and she will not be able to return to her daughter.  Therefore, the OP will need to eat dinner with her daughter before retrieving her bags.

Comment: More than once I've missed a connection while my bag(s) made the connection. At least one of those times, my bag did make it to the baggage carousel (my travel partner saw it -- his first class seat let him make the tight connection), I just retrieved it from the luggage office when I arrived.

Answer (score 9):

I assume you are travelling to IAH on a domestic (or pre-cleared) flight. [Otherwise, you will not have a chance to find a restaurant until you have passed through US Customs, and you'll have to take your bag before customs or you will find it very difficult to retrieve later.]

Your baggage will remain on the carousel for some time. If the same carousel is subsequently used for another flight, then your bag may end up mixed with other bags. Alternatively, the baggage staff may remove it and store it at baggage services: they know people can be delayed claiming their luggage for many reasons. However you will appreciate that in this day and age, unattended articles can cause suspicion.

Leaving your bag unattended also slightly increases the chance of theft (the domestic baggage claim is open to the street) or a mix up where someone honestly takes the wrong bag. However, it is probably not too much to worry about in the grand scheme of things.

You are probably better off travelling light and keeping a small bag in the cabin with you. If you have to "gate check" a slightly oversized bag it will be returned to you at the gate when you arrive at IAH.

Comment: My experience is that they'll eventually remove it and store it somewhere in the airport, but having them actually find it again and give it to you can be a problematic and slow process. I've been shown into rooms in the depths of the airport filled with random luggage and asked to see if I can find mine anywhere. And that's assuming someone doesn't walk off with it.

Answer (score 2):

All that is *supposed* to happen is that it revolves sadly around the baggage carousel until a porter from the luggage office comes and puts it behind the luggage desk, where you can wait in line later and retrieve it from a sullen clerk.

But a million other things might happen.  Someone might, innocently or not, walk off with it.  The space reserved for storing such bags might be full and your bag will be dispatched off to some remote part of the airport.  The bag might never arrive and you won't get much sympathy from the lost-luggage people.

My point is, you are leaving a lot to chance.  If your bag is so gigantic and wheeling it to a restaurant is such a burden that this sort of risk makes sense, consider packing more lightly.

Comment: She wants to eat dinner in a restaurant in the secured area of the airport, which she must leave to get her bag.  Taking the bag to the restaurant is not an option.

Comment: @phoog -- is the particular restaurant special?  Better I would think to get your bags, eat somewhere outside the security line, and then have the daughter go back through screening.  There's a Chilli's in the baggage area.

Comment: Indeed, if that's the case then someone should suggest that, which seems to be a possibility that Maggie did not consider. I would have suggested it, but the US airports I know mostly have terrible food options by baggage claim, if any.

Comment: @Malvolio The only downside to that is that her daughter would have to clear security again to catch her connecting flight and TSA wait times have been horrendous at several of the major US hubs lately. I'm not sure what IAH is like, but American announced that it's had 70,000 passengers miss flights because of TSA security lines so far this year. Delta and United have been similarly fed up with TSA. Perhaps most prominently, both the administration of Atlanta International and the Port Authority of New York and New Jersey have recently threatened to kick TSA out of their airports.

Comment: @reirab -- "Threatened"?  Why bother to threaten?  If threats worked, the *inherent* threat of being kicked out would have reformed the TSA a decade ago.  My home airport is SFO, and the private security they use _is_ responsive to threats, they know that the airport authorities can and will replace them the day they become an obstruction to airport operations, so they are reasonably polite and efficient (and fire anyone who is not).  The TSA knows that even if Port Authority kicks them out, no TSA employee will lose his job.

Comment: @Malvolio I'm all for privatizing them, but I'm curious about your last sentence. Why do you think no TSA employee would lose their job? What would all of the JFK/LGA/EWR screeners do if Port Authority replaced them with private screeners?

Comment: @reirab -- Federal layoffs are very rare.  If TSA lost a big contract, they would probably try to move idle employees to other duties.  Certainly, something that would never occur to them that the employees from a specific airport that privatized _ought_ to be laid off, since the airport was unhappy with them.  In any case, if employees were terminated, it would not be according to performance, so any given TSA employee at, JFK, has only a tiny incentive to work harder, since he has a minuscule effect on the whole contract and certainly his own managers won't hold him directly accountable.